# How to pattern match head in a list in function?

Tags: list, functional-programming, elixir, pattern-matching

I have a list of mix of integer and atom. I want to match the head of the list with atom otherwise integer.

```elixir
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6, :eoe, 7,8,9,10,11,12. :eoe]
```

I initially tried this way:

```elixir
defmodule Test do
  def test(lst) do
    helper(lst, 0, 0, 1)
  end

  def helper([], _p, total, e) do
    IO.puts "#{e} #{t}"
  end

  def helper([:eoe , t], _p, total, e) do   # <--- This function never called even though head is at some point :eoe
    IO.puts "#{e} #{total}"

    helper(t, "", 0, elf + 1)
  end

  def helper([h | t], p, total, e) do
    h
    |> is_atom()
    |> IO.inspect()

    helper(t, h, total + h, e)

  end
end
```

then added guards to explicitly narrow down pattern matching

```elixir
...

def helper([:eoe = head , t], _p, total, e) when is_atom(head) do
...

def helper([h | t], p, total, e) when is_integer(h) do
...
```

`def helper([:eoe = h , t], _p, total, e) when is_atom(h) do` this function does't get called. It always matches `def helper([h | t], p, total, e) when is_integer(h) do` this one. I even placed the former one before latter one. I would expect it be matched against `:eoe`

Comment: Try with `[:eoe = h | t]` instead of `[:eoe = h, t]` ;)

Comment: I can't believe it's a syntax error. I was losing my mind. @BrujoBenavides

Comment: Been there, done that. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To match the head one should use the `[h | t]` notation. `[h, t]` would match the list of **two** elements.

```
- def helper([:eoe = h, t]
+ def helper([:eoe = h | t]
```

Also, `when is_atom(h)` guard is redundant, once you pattern-match directly on the atom. That said, any of the following would do.

```elixir
def helper([:eoe | t], _p, total, e) do
def helper([h | t], _p, total, e) when h == :eoe do
def helper([h | t], _p, total, e) when h in [:eoe] do
def helper([h | t], _p, total, e) when is_atom(h) do # match any atom
```

Comment: I added the guard to explicitly narrow down the pattern matching because I thought something was odd and it turns out it was a syntax error.

Comment: There might be future visitors with the same issue, thus answers on this site argue with the original question :)